# Azure elastic pool: Can I create as many databases as I want?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure

I am sitting here trying to figure out what the elastic pool in Azure gives me. I have a customer that wants a guess on pricing if they move to Azure. They have 3 databases, on a server. The server has 96 GBs of RAM and a 3.4 Ghz processor. That is *all* I know. The three databases are sharing these specs, and each database has it own area of expertise:

1. one database handles all the CMS data
2. the second database handles all the commerce data
3. the third database is a database that stores user info, etc - all data that doesn't fit the two others

I think the usage pattern is pretty diverse, so sometimes the commerce DB is using a lot of RAM and CPU, other times it is the CMS DB etc.

I don't think they fit well into a single database, because they are going to need three big databases then, and almost all of them are going to be under-utilized all the time. So I thought about elastic pools.

The description of elastic pools fits the above very well: all databases share eDTUs. Perfect! But one thing the docs don't describe is: do I pay for the elastic pool AND per database? Or do I just create databases on the fly, and all of them share, that is: the databases are free, but you pay for the eDTU?

I have read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool - but it doesn't describe my situation.

Hope someone can give me some more info.

**EDIT**
They are going to update the docs: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49201#issuecomment-593579476. I created an issue for this asking for clarification.

Comment: Do the databases have a lot of queries that use the other databases? This will drive most of your decision making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When under the eDTU model you can create databases as you see fit and calculate your cost with the [pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/#sql-databasea99d81e8-2319-419b-a0c6-a52a79a16e8d). This shows that you pay per pool, the amount of databases do not matter.

You do have a maximum amount of databases you can create. This is based on your [service tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers-dtu) *(basic, standard, premium*) & performance level (eDTUs & storage).

[image]

Also found in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers-dtu)

[image]

The vCore elastic pool maximum amount of databases per pool are noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vcore-resource-limits-elastic-pools).

A small example for a subset of Gen5 General Purpose elastic pool:

[image]

---

As a side note since you only have 3 databases to be added in your elastic pool, to be cost effective remember that:

> If the aggregate amount of resources for single databases is more than
>   1.5x the resources needed for the pool, then an elastic pool is more cost effective.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool#minimum-number-of-databases)

Answer (score 3):

> The server has 96 GBs of RAM and a 3.4 Ghz processor

The elastic pool is mainly for smaller workloads, and multi-tenant applications.  For lift-and-shift of existing SQL Servers, you're normally better-off with [Azure SQL Database Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/what-is-azure-sql-database-managed-instance-2).

Only Managed Instance (or SQL Server on an Azure VM) supports cross-database queries, SQL Server Linked Servers, Transactional Replication publication and distribution, SQL Agent, and other features an on-prem SQL Server may be using.

Managed Instance starts at 4 vCores, where Elastic Pool is available in smaller sizes, down to less than 1 vCore.

Comment: You can do cross-database queries in elastic pool. It just requires set up. For a handful of queries, I find it is acceptable.

Comment: I actually think that the customer has a too big database for their workload, and that is also why I am asking for info on the elastic pool. I do not know if an elastic pool, or 3 single databases would be sufficient, but i want to provide them with both solutions.

Comment: @AnthonyGenovese  Elastic Query is a suitable replacement for cross-database query in some applications.